# How can I edit crontab of root having only the remote hard disk and without chrooting?

Tags: cron

Case scenario:

- I have received the **hard disk** of a remote **Linux** (say Debian based) computer.
- The remote hardware (say **RaspBerry**, so ARM) is not compatible with mine (say PC, so AMD64), so `chroot` is not possible.
- I need to add **CRON tasks** (say some `adduser newuser` command) with admin privileges to the remote system.
- We can assume partitions format is some *NIX compatible (say `Ext3` or `Ext4`), so I **can mount**, read and edit the root partition (say `Raspbian`, a common Ubuntu-like operating system for Raspberry).

After editing the hard disk (say Micro SD card, as long as the example is RaspBerry based), I will boot the remote system with it and my CRON task must execute.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. The system-wide `crontab` file is usually located at `/etc/crontab` with overrides in `/etc/cron.d`, so assuming you have mounted the root partition of the remote computer's disk at `/mnt`, you should be able to locate them at `/mnt/etc/crontab` and modify with the text editor of your choice.

The per-user `crontab` files are usually located in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` on Debian and derivatives, and you should be able to edit them in the same way (although the manpage to crontab discourages this).

Answer (score 1):

Crontabs are simple text files stored in standard locations, that are then read by `cron`. The `crontab` program lets you edit these files, but check the format is correct before saving them. I guess it also signals the `cron` daemon to read the new version.

So mostly this mechanism is intended as a way not to mess you up if you make a mistake. (It's also setgid so it can edit crontabs in the standard directory.) But if you know your format is correct, nothing prevents you from directly editing crontabs, especially on a mounted drive when there's no cron using them.

User crontabs are stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`, the filename corresponding to the account name. But you probably want to use the system crontab as AdminBee mentioned, that is `/etc/crontab` or (to keep things organized) inside `/etc/crontab.d/`. On Debian there are also `/etc/cron.monthly/`, `/etc/cron.weekly/`, `/etc/cron.daily/`, and `/etc/cron.hourly/` where you can just drop executable files (mostly intended for packages but there's nothing wrong in using them yourself).

Note I'm using my Debian machine and manpages as reference, check those paths for your target distro beforehand.